# W8/XAML GridView -> Align Header Element to the Right

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-8

I want the Headers of my GridView to Contain the Groups Name on the Left and a Symbol on the right and did this.:

```
                    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>

                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition
                                        Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                    <ColumnDefinition
                                        Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <Button
                                    Grid.Column="0"
                                    AutomationProperties.Name="Group Title"
                                    Style="{StaticResource TextPrimaryButtonStyle}" />


                                    <Button
                                        Grid.Column="1"
                                        Content="&#xE0A1;"></Button>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
```

Unfortunally the Symbol is always on the left right next to the group title.:

[image]

**How can i right align elements in a group header?**

*Edit.: Fixed sizes of Grids Columns dont work out because the groups can vary in Width depending on screen and number of items in individual group.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a very nice solution on the msdn forums. Here it is:

**First of all write a converter** to calculate the width of the Container in the Datatemplate, in my case the grid:

```
class WidthConverter : IValueConverter
{
    #region IValueConverter Member

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        int x;
        if (parameter != null)
            x = int.Parse(parameter.ToString());
        else
            x = 1;
        if ((int)value % x == 0)
            return (int)value / x * 260 - 5;
        else
            return ((int)value / x + 1) * 260 - 5;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Now **declare it in your page´s resources:**

```
<local:WidthConverter x:Key="WidthConverter"/>
```

Finally use a binding to put it in use and calculate the Grid´s width:

```
<Grid Width="{Binding Items.Count, Converter={StaticResource WidthConverter}, ConverterParameter=2}">
```

**Set the converter Parameter to the number of row`s displayed**, that depends on screen resolutions if you dont limit it.

**Replace 260 in the Converter wit a number matching your itemstemplate size`s and margins.**

Answer (score 0):

The are probably many ways to do this.  The simplest would be to set the column widths in the data template grid. In your code above, change the `width="*"` to the following:

```
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="200"></ColumnDefinition>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50"></ColumnDefinition>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
```

The total of the widths is equal to 250, which is the standard grid cell size.

You may have to adjust these numbers depending on your actual requirements.

Comment: Unfortunally this solution doesnt work out for me because of the variety of group width´s depending on screen resolution and number of items in the individual group.